# what is the difference between constant and changing magnetic and electric fields? How do they occur? How do they form an electromagnetic wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

what is the difference between constant and changing magnetic and electric fields? How do they occur?
How do they form an electromagnetic wave?

Answer (score 1):

Constant Electric and Magnetic Fields are constant in magnitude and Direction. Changing Electric and Magnetic Fields are Not.

For the answer on how do they form a wave, see the picture below,
[image: Production of Electromagnetic Waves]

Comment: In free space the zero crossings of the field should be everywhere simultaneous.